# URL Rewrite when WordPress is in subdirectory

Tags: url-rewriting, directory

I have a website with WordPress installed in a subdirectory called "articles." The rest of the site is built outside of WordPress.

I'm wondering if it's possible to rewrite the author page URLs from:

> mysite.com/articles/author/persons-name

to

> mysite.com/team/persons-name

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your .htaccess file to achieve what you want.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\.html$ /articles/author/persons-name [L]
```